# Getting six and six.moves modules to autocomplete in PyCharm?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, autocomplete, pycharm, six

Is it possible to get imports for the six module to work in PyCharm? I realize the module does some playing with imports that confuses PyCharm but I was hoping there was some type of workaround.

For example, I'd like the following to work properly in PyCharm or IntelliJ::

```py
from six.moves import BaseHTTPServer
```

Answer (score 3):

The imports are dynamic so pycharm can't do any static analysis of the code to determine the type information.

Pycharm gets around this for languages like javascript by using static type definition files (Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Javascript -> Libraries).

This is the python equivalent:
 https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.2/using-python-skeletons.html - a parallel set of python files with static exports allowing static analysis.

At the present time the skeleton definitions seem to really be a proof of concept as they are *very* sparse (there is no `six`, and while a `django` module exists it is almost empty -- there is no `django.utils.six.moves` that you could just copy over). You could manually add all the `six.moves` exports but this would be a non-trivial effort.

If you did want to try modifying the skeleton files, on OSX:

`cd ~/Library/Preferences/PyCharm2016.2
git clone https://github.com/JetBrains/python-skeletons.git`

and modify files in there (although I was never actually able to get it to detect my changes)