# PyCharm from six.moves import queue: unresolved reference 'queue'

Tags: pycharm, six

I have installed the module "six", and it can be found by the PyCharm Interpreter.

**PyCharm Interpreter:**

[image]

However, PyCharm reports that it cannot resolve reference 'queue' which should be imported from six.

**Unresolved reference queue:**

[image]

Comment: Maybe you installed the wrong version? Check that `moves` is indeed present in the module.

Comment: This answer is relevant for working around this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38720340/823942

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. This is because moved attributes and modules in `six` are loaded lazily, therefore PyCharm cannot resolve the reference.

See source code for class `Module_six_moves_urllib_parse` in `six.py`.

Comment: This is still a bug in PyCharm. Reported as [youtrack PY-24207](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-24207). Cast your vote today.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, if you have six imported you can import queue as follows:

```
import six
import queue
```

It just worked for me, hope it works for you as well.